# How can you design a 1920px by 1080px WinForm on a computer with a maximum resolution of 1366x768?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing an winforms application on my notebook (Screen Resolution: 1366x768). The terminal device for the application is windows surface (Screen Resolution 1920x1080). Now I want to make my forms and user controls bigger so that they can fit full screen on the surface. I´v done this with this code on my main form:

```
        Left = Top = 0;
        Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width;
        Height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height;
```

But in my UserControls I need to place the buttons textboxes etc. on the right position. Otherwise a large area of the Application is unused. So I need to make the size of the user control and forms bigger but the screen resolution of my notebook is too small so it wouldn't allow numbers above 1366x768 pixels. How can I still design the application for the screen resolution of the surface?

Comment: One question at a time, please.  Regarding your title question, why exactly can't you set the resolution higher than your notebook?  Are you using the designer?

Comment: Sorry for the double question but the questions are in some way related to each other. Yes i am using the designer of visual studio. I just noticed that i can change the user controls sizes to higher numbers then my screen resolution but not the size of my main form. Why is that so?

Comment: You can just avoid using the designer.  Sometimes I've seen it impose weird constraints.  I would suggest simply assigning the desired values in code.  Don't change them in the designer file as it's auto-generated.

Comment: Okay i can do it with avoiding the designer. But what about positioning some buttons on that form. How to do that without seeing the full range of your layout on the designer?

Comment: Use a TableLayoutPanel to position and size your controls relative to the size of the form.

Comment: You already have two close votes for this being too broad.  If you limit this question to: How can you design a 1920px by 1080px WinForm on a computer with a maximum resolution of 1366x768?, That problem is easily solved and you may get an answer.

Comment: @TnTinMn I changed it. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is a direct translation (via a tool) from a VB.Net [answer that I posted several years ago on CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Messages/4599323/Re-Discussion-on-Screen-Size-and-MDI.aspx), so it will look strange when viewed through the current C# fashion trend lens. However it is functional on Windows based PC's.

Add this `Form` definition to your project.  Perform a build.  Then you can use the Inherited Form item template to add a Form derived from this one.  Via the propertygrid, set the `MaxDesignWidth` and `MaxDesignHeight` properties to the values that match your target resolution.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

---

```
public class FormWithDesignSize : Form
{
    private const Int32 DefaultMax = 2000; //set this to whatever you need

    private Int32 _MaxDesignWidth = DefaultMax;
    private Int32 _MaxDesignHeight = DefaultMax;

    [Category("Design"), DisplayName("MaxDesignWidth")]
    public Int32 aaa_MaxDesignWidth //Prefix aaa_ is to force Designer code placement before ClientSize setting
    {
        get // avoids need to write customer serializer code
        {
            return _MaxDesignWidth;
        }
        set
        {
            _MaxDesignWidth = value;
        }
    }

    [Category("Design"), DisplayName("MaxDesignHeight")]
    public Int32 aaa_MaxDesignHeight //Prefix aaa_ is to force Designer code placement before ClientSize setting
    {
        get // avoids need to write customer serializer code
        {
            return _MaxDesignHeight;
        }
        set
        {
            _MaxDesignHeight = value;
        }
    }


    protected override void SetBoundsCore(Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, BoundsSpecified specified)
    {
        if (this.DesignMode)
        {
            // The Forms.Form.SetBoundsCore method limits the size based on SystemInformation.MaxWindowTrackSize

            // From the GetSystemMetrics function documentation for SMCXMINTRACK: 
            //   "The minimum tracking width of a window, in pixels. The user cannot drag the window frame to a size 
            //    smaller than these dimensions. A window can override this value by processing the WMGETMINMAXINFO
            //    message."
            // See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

            // This message also appears to control the size set by the MoveWindow API, 
            // so it is intercepted and the maximum size is set to MaxWidth by MaxHeight
            // in the WndProc method when in DesignMode.

            // Form.SetBoundsCore ultimately calls Forms.Control.SetBoundsCore that calls SetWindowPos but, 
            // MoveWindow will be used instead to set the Window size when in the designer as it requires less
            // parameters to achieve the desired effect.

            MoveWindow(this.Handle, this.Left, this.Top, width, height, true);
        }
        else
        {
            base.SetBoundsCore(x, y, width, height, specified);
        }
    }

    private const Int32 WMGETMINMAXINFO = 0x24;
    protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        if (this.DesignMode && m.Msg == WMGETMINMAXINFO)
        {

            MINMAXINFO MMI = new MINMAXINFO();
            // retrieve default MINMAXINFO values from the structure pointed to by m.LParam
            Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, MMI);

            // reset the ptMaxTrackSize value
            MMI.ptMaxTrackSize = new POINTAPI(_MaxDesignWidth, _MaxDesignHeight);

            // copy the modified structure back to LParam
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(MMI, m.LParam, true);
        }

    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private class MINMAXINFO
    {
        public POINTAPI ptReserved;
        public POINTAPI ptMaxSize;
        public POINTAPI ptMaxPosition;
        public POINTAPI ptMinTrackSize;
        public POINTAPI ptMaxTrackSize;
    }

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct POINTAPI
    {
        public Int32 X;
        public Int32 Y;

        public POINTAPI(Int32 X, Int32 Y) : this()
        {
            this.X = X;
            this.Y = Y;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "(" + X.ToString() + ", " + Y.ToString() + ")";
        }
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private extern static bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 nWidth, Int32 nHeight, bool bRepaint);

}
```