# Unable to set WinForm MinimumSize.Width Larger than 1278

Tags: vb.net

I want to set the `MinimumSize` of my form to W:1610, H:750 as this is the minimum size to accommodate all of the controls properly.

However, if I change the `MinimumSize.Width` property  to anything greater than 1278, it reverts automatically back to this value (in design view). If I set the size programmatically it seems to be ignored.

`MinimumSize = New Size(1610, 750)`

What's going on here and how do I get around this?

Comment: Whats you current screen resolution you are designing on?

Comment: There is a rock-hard check inside winforms that ensures you cannot create a window that is larger than the screen.  That check is active both at design and runtime.  Keep your system requirements in mind, your user would need a monitor that's large enough to accommodate your layout.  That's pretty hard to do, users always ignore that, and requires you to follow that requirement as well.  Not declaring your app to be dpiAware can be an issue as well, but normally only bytes at runtime.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant, I suspected that might be the case. Is there a better way I could handle the rearranging/hiding of the controls rather than just overlapping them?

Comment: You could use a tabstrip

Comment: Or put everything inside a Panel and set its AuoScroll property to True.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54815288/how-can-you-design-a-1920px-by-1080px-winform-on-a-computer-with-a-maximum-resol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54815288/how-can-you-design-a-1920px-by-1080px-winform-on-a-computer-with-a-maximum-resol)